# Android: Tweetie Style List Refresh

Tags: android, listview

I've come from iPhone background and am writing an android app.

I've got a list which is cached locally, but primary is stored on the our webserver as the app is an interface to our service. What I really want is a simple way for the user to refresh the list. So I'm trying to replicate the tweetie pulldown to refresh list.

Does anybody know how to hide the ListView header row, so that android believes the top is the first list item, and it naturally stops scrolling there, but if you pull the list down more it reveals the "refresh" header which stays on screen until the refresh is done and then goes back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this widget:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh